# Does making a member private or internal help the compiler make optimizations?

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading Eric Lippert's post

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

So I am wondering what a developer can do to can help the C# compiler make optimizations, such as using the stack instead of the heap. For example, if you make a property internal to an assembly instead of protected/public, the compiler could consider that a guarantee that the property won't be seen outside the assembly and therefore not possibly referenced.

```
class Foo {
    internal Object Bar;
}
```

Obviously there is a fine line between fighting the compiler for optimizations and writing code that is actually more correct than your QA / unit testing requires as to help the compiler make stronger assumptions about it.

I am also wondering what other things can help the optimizer and are also worth the effort in the sense that they increase correctness.

Comment: Yes. Slightly. Don't even bother, though. If you aren't having problems, don't try to find a bottleneck. If something isn't a bottleneck, don't optimize it.

Comment: This is absolutely a pre-optimization scenario.  Access modifiers should be used for proper encapsulation and abstraction, not optimization.  Focus on protecting your code from invalid access over marginal performance gains.

Comment: How eric's article is related here? He talks about value type where as no value type involved here. btw Why does it even matter for you whether it goes to stack or heap?

Comment: It's more likely that the *JIT* will perform optimization than the C# compiler...

Comment: I think @ericlippert is still around and you might even get lucky if he chooses to comment =)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, whether something goes on the stack or the heap can make or break performance requirements.

Comment: @NickStrupat In a very small number of highly critical sections of code in applications that inherently have very high demands on performance.  In contrast, the vast majority of code written in non-performance intensive applications, and the entirety of all remaining applications, don't need to care about this at all.

Comment: Remember that private/internal members can still be accessed through reflection. Given that there's probably very little the compiler/JIT compiler will actually do in the way of optimizations based on access modifiers.

Comment: @zespri: Could happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am wondering what a developer can do to can help the C# compiler make optimizations, such as using the stack instead of the heap.

That's a noble aim but you're going about it backwards. Rather than saying "how can I write my program to help the compiler generate good code?" ask "is my program unacceptably slow?" If it is then use a *profiler* to find the slowest part, then figure out *why* it is so slow, and then ask "what can I do to make this code faster?"

For example: in Roslyn we discovered that a significant fraction of the time cost of the compiler was associated with garbage collection of the zillions of temporary objects that are created during semantic analysis. We decided to solve this problem using a variety of techniques, such as pooling strategies, lazy allocation, carefully tuned caches and an architecture that allowed large objects to be thrown away and recomputed later on demand if necessary.

Our attitude was always "we have to make sure this is fast" but the way we ensured that was not by trying to write the program up front to be fast. Instead what we did was wrote a performance test suite very early so that we could monitor every day whether yesterday's checkins had introduced a performance regression; this allowed us to quickly learn what techniques were making improvements and what were making regressions.

Performance is a *feature*, so design it like any other feature. Set goals, write tests that verify that you've met those goals. "Tips and tricks" for writing fast code are generally worthless; performance comes out of the *process* of using good empirical engineering techniques.

To address your specific question:

> Does making a member private or internal help the compiler make optimizations?

The question presupposes that you'd take a public property and make it private because that's faster. But a property is public *because a customer needs to use it*. The reason to make a member private is because *it's an implementation detail of the class*, not because the compiler might be able to find an optimization.

There are a few ways that you can help the compiler make *very small* optimizations. For example:

```
class Fruit {}
class Apple : Fruit {}
class Orange : Fruit {}
...
Fruit[] fruits = new Apple[10];
```

Oh the pain. C# supports unsafe array covariance. When you say

```
fruits[0] = new Apple();
```

the runtime must generate a check that says "is `fruits` actually an `Orange[]`? Because if it is, we need to throw an exception."  This is unavoidable. Now consider:

```
Apple[] apples = MakeAppleArray();
apples[0] = someApple;
```

Now, is the runtime check necessary here as well?  Yes. `apples` might be `GrannySmith[]` and `someApple` might be `RedDelicious`, so the check is necessary.  But suppose you said

```
sealed class Apple : Fruit {}
```

Now the runtime knows that `apples` cannot possibly really be `GrannySmith[]` because there is no such type. It might be able to save a few *nanoseconds* by knowing that `Apple` is sealed.

Again, saving a few nanoseconds is not a good reason to seal a class. **Expressing the intention that the class was not designed for further inheritance** is the reason to seal a class.

Similarly, if the compiler sees

```
X M() { return new X(); }
...
M().Foo(); // instance method
```

then the compiler will generate code that checks to see whether M() returned null before instance method Foo is called, because it is not smart enough to realize that M() never returns null. But if you say

```
(new X()).Foo();
```

then the compiler reasons "this either throws or produces a valid reference, therefore the null check can be removed". The compiler *is* smart here. Writing the code the second way instead of the first way could save up to two or three nanoseconds. **It's not worth it**. Don't write your code to try to take advantage of the compiler's little tricks; you will never, ever notice the difference.  *There are no programs in the app store that sold a million copies because they elided a null check and saved a nanosecond.*

Answer (score 0):

> So I am wondering what a developer can do to can help the C# compiler make optimizations, such as using the stack instead of the heap.

Nothing.  The C# compiler does very little in the way of optimizing.  It certainly does nothing along the lines of using the stack over the heap based on the access modifiers you apply to your code.

The only way to control stack vs. heap at this time is to use `struct` instead of `class`.  However that is still really a CLR decision, not C#.  C# doesn't really have any notion of stack or heap, just lifetime of values.